# Strange characters with diff-match-patch libraries

Tags: java, diff

I'm using diff-match-patch (https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/) to get the difference between two texts. At the end of the diff, they return strange characters: for example `à` become `%C3%A0`, `ù` `%C3%B9`, `"` `%22` and so on.

This is an example of my code:

```
String startDocument = "hello world";
String endDocument = "àèìòù\"";
diff_match_patch dmp = new diff_match_patch();
dmp.Diff_Timeout = 16;
LinkedList<Diff> diffs = dmp.diff_main( startDocument, endDocument );
String diff = dmp.diff_toDelta(diffs);
System.out.println(diff);      //return: -11 +%C3%A0%C3%A8%C3%AC%C3%B2%C3%B9%22
```

How can I retrieve the original characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
javac -encoding utf8 DaClass.java
```

and

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 DaClass
```

Comment: The other characters manipulated in the class aren't wrong, only the diff function return this strange characters...

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior.

DiffMatchPatch uses javascript's-like encoding of special characters (from [the project's wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/wikis/Unidiff.wiki)):

> #### 2. Encoded Characters
>
> Special characters are encoded using %xx notation. The set of
>   characters which are encoded matches JavaScript's encodeURI()
>   function, with the exception of spaces which are not encoded.

In order to decode it just look at [the code](https://web.archive.org/web/20121226190221/http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/source/browse/trunk/java/name/fraser/neil/plaintext/diff_match_patch.java#1482):

```
// decode would change all "+" to " "
param = param.replace("+", "%2B");
try {
    param = URLDecoder.decode(param, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // Not likely on modern system.
    throw new Error("This system does not support UTF-8.", e);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Malformed URI sequence.
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal escape in diff_fromDelta: " + param, e);
}
diffs.add(new Diff(Operation.INSERT, param));
```

Actually you don't need to decode equalities or removals since it doesn't include their text in delta format.

If you are just trying to display differences look at the [`diff_prettyHtml`](https://web.archive.org/web/20121226190221/http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/source/browse/trunk/java/name/fraser/neil/plaintext/diff_match_patch.java#1340) method.